# Flutter carousel image slider open separate page during on tap event is called

Tags: dart, flutter

Im new to flutter. I would like to ask a question about my code. I have take a look on youtube and some google tutorial on this inkwell and on tap function to open new class activity on flutter.But the result is, when the image is tapped it open different image screen but they share same class file.

How can I have a separate page for different image click. For example,
I have five image in my flutter carousel slider.
Image 1 will open sliderpage 1. Image 2 will open sliderpage 2 and so on.Means they are on separate page instead of different image open same page but only show different images. Im trying this tutorial but they do have same page but different images displayed after on tap event is called. url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9XOUoJsdy4

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Widget image_carousel = new Container(
      height: 345.0,

      child: new Carousel(
        boxFit: BoxFit.fill,
        images: [
          AssetImage('assets/s7.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/s3.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/s5.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/s2.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/s4.jpg'),
        ],
        autoplay: true,
        animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        dotColor: Colors.red[50],
        dotSize: 4.0,
        indicatorBgPadding: 2.0,
      ),


    );

    return Scaffold(

      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          image_carousel,

       //grid view
       Container(
         height:163.0,
         child: Products(),
       )


        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On this code, this code just display carousel image without any event on click is done , I was expecting to have different page routing by on tap event is happen when image assets is clicked and navigate to different pages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, you need to install [carousel_slider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/carousel_slider), then create two screens:

The first one will contain carousel_slider when you click on the image it will navigate to the second screen and passing image URL of the image you clicked on, To have on tap event you need to wrap you Image widget with `GestureDetector`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import './image_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Demo()));

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<Demo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget image_carousel = new Container(
        height: 345.0,
        child: CarouselSlider(
          height: 400.0,
          items: [
            'http://pic3.16pic.com/00/55/42/16pic_5542988_b.jpg',
            'http://photo.16pic.com/00/38/88/16pic_3888084_b.jpg',
            'http://pic3.16pic.com/00/55/42/16pic_5542988_b.jpg',
            'http://photo.16pic.com/00/38/88/16pic_3888084_b.jpg'
          ].map((i) {
            return Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Image.network(i, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push<Widget>(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ImageScreen(i),
                            ),
                          );
                        }));
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        ));

    return Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          image_carousel,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The second screen will contain only the image you clicked on:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  ImageScreen(this.url);

  @override
  _MyImageScreen createState() => _MyImageScreen(url);
}

class _MyImageScreen extends State<ImageScreen> {
  final String url;
  _MyImageScreen(this.url);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('ImageScreen'),
        ),
        body: Image.network(url, width: double.infinity));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Lets say I have five screen for five image url can I use your method. Your method state that one home screen will navigate to second screen when the user interact with the image. Is it possible for me to have each image navigate to different screen. Means five screen class for five images in carousel slider.

Comment: I have made five screen when each image is pressed on carousel slider and named it as slider_pageone, slider_pagetwo, slider_pagethree, slider_pagefour, and slider_pagefive. Each of this will trigger only when specific image linked to this page is clicked from carousel slider homepage.

Comment: Why would you create 5 screens just use one screen and passe different URL, what if you have 100 images do you want to create 100 screens, of course not just one screen with different parameter `url`.

Comment: One more thing, for network image do I need to specify its url inside pubspec.yaml just like local assets images.

Comment: I am planning to create different screen for promotions, games, news, and so on they have to link on different pages when carousel images is pressed.

Comment: You can use `Image.network` only if images are remotely loaded, I used it because I don't have your images so I used random images from the net, but if you have images included in you assert you need t use `AssetImage` instead of `Image.network`.

Comment: I see. Alright noted. Thanks again for your answer, I will try customise it to navigate on different pages.

Comment: how can I add share,download,set as wallpaper options

Comment: we need to use this as per latest updates options: CarouselOptions(height: 400.0)

Comment: @flitz did you customise it to navigate on different pages. if yes please tell how to do