# How to create carousel slider with firestore image and onclick launch url in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, slider, carousel

I want to create carousel slider in flutter with cloud firestore. I created cloud firestore collection with the name of "slider" and i have two fields one is "image" and another one is "url".

Now i need to stream firestore collection in my carousel slider and when user click image, want to launch url.

**My Carousel Slider Code**

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 15.0),
        CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
              height: 400.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              autoPlay: true,
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
              autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
              viewportFraction: 0.8),
          items: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('$show Firestore image'),
                  onPressed: () {
              launchURL(
                  "$ launch firestore url");
            }
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var idx = 1;
return Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, bottom: 8.0),
height: getProportionateScreenHeight(150),
width: double.infinity,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Color(0xFF4A3298),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
),
child:StreamBuilder(
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(BANNER_URL).snapshots(),
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
List list = []..length;

```
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return Container(
                child: Center(
                    child: new Text(
                        'No network. \nPlease, check the connection.')),
              );
              break;
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Container(
                child: Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator()),
              );
              break;
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                  ),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.size; i++) {
                  debugPrint("Index is " + idx.toString());
                  list.add(NetworkImage(
                      snapshot.data.docs[i].data()['image_url']));
                  idx++;
                }
                return  ClipRect(
                  child: Banner(
                      message: "Publicite aqui",
                      location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
                      color: Colors.red,

                      child:  Carousel(
                        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                        images: list,
                        autoplay: true,
                        animationCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                        dotSize: 2.0,
                        dotColor: AppTheme.cuyuyuOrange400,
                        dotBgColor: AppTheme.cuyuyuTransparent,
                        indicatorBgPadding: 2.0,
                      )),
                );
              }

          }
        }),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a FutureBuilder to fetch the document snapshot, and on completion, you can store the URLs in a list and use the list for the Carousel

Example code which uses FutureBuilder to fetch a list of urls:

```
Future getCarouselWidget() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("carousel").getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var idx = 1;
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getCarouselWidget(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            List<NetworkImage> list = new List<NetworkImage>();
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return new CircularProgressIndicator(); 
            } else {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return new Text("fetch error");
              } else {

                //Create for loop and store the urls in the list 
                for(int i = 0; i < snapshot.data[0].data.length; i++ ) {
                  debugPrint("Index is " + idx.toString());
                  list.add(NetworkImage(snapshot.data[0].data["img_"+idx.toString()]));
                  idx++;
                }
                return new Container(
                    height: 250.0,
                    child: new Carousel(
                      boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                      images: list,   <== Set the list here 
                      autoplay: true,
                      dotSize: 4.0,
                      indicatorBgPadding: 4.0,
                      animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                    ));
              }
            }
          }),
    );
```

Comment: Thank u but I need to open url (like https://google.com) when user click carousel slider image and that url i need to fetch from Firestore. How to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413525/flutter-carousel-image-slider-open-separate-page-during-on-tap-event-is-called
this explains the onTap function, you just have to generate that list from your document snapshot

next time, please make sure to add it in your problem statement